# Non-negative function with infinitely many positive values -- must integral be positive?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Assume $g$ is integrable and $g(x) \ge 0$ on $[a, b]$. If $g(x) > 0$ for an infinite number of points $x \in [a,b]$, then $\int_a^b g > 0$.

I thought this was true but I saw a link [link](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgar/Teach/2005_311/2005_05_06homeworksolutions.pdf) saying its false (with no proof or reasoning)

My thought is this: If $g$ is integrable then $\int (g) = U(g) = L(g)$ and we know

$\int (g) \ge 0 \implies$ suppose $U(g) = 0$ then for all partitions, $U(f,P) = \sum( M_k \cdot (x_k - x_{k-1})) = 0$ but, since there are infinitely many $x$ s.t. $g(x) >0$. Then for some $k \in \{1,\ldots, n\}, M_k = \sup\{g(x) : x \in [x_k-1, x_k]\} > 0 \implies U(f,P) > 0 \implies \int (g) > 0$

I'm guessing if this is wrong it has something to do with $g$ not being continuous and leaving the possibility that $M_k$ is in fact not greater than $0$? But if $M_k = \sup \{g(x) : x \in [x_k-1, x_k]\}$, then even if $g(x) \to \infty$, $\infty > 0$, no?

Comment: Please learn to use MathJax from https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following function:

Let $A = \{ \frac1{n}: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $[a,b]=[0,1]$.

$$g(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &, x \in A \\
0 &, x \not \in A \text{ and } x\in [0,1] \end{cases}$$

then since this function has only countably many discontinuity, the function is Riemann integrable, furthermore, the function integrate to $0$.

Comment: thanks for the reply! Follow up question: using your examples given that we partition [0,1] using A, let g(x_k) = g(x_k+1) = 1, does the supremum of g(x) for x in [x_k,x_k+1] not equal 1?

Comment: Or are the elements of the partition supposed to be of form x - epsilon, x + epsilon, for x in A

Comment: intuition for riemann integral, as you approximate the area under the graph, we have to use rectangles that are finer and finer to approximate the area. This area converges to $0$ if the dicontinuity is countable.

Comment: Gotcha and for something like g(x) = 1 if x in Q and 0 if x not in Q, is not integrable because there are uncountably many discontinuities, correct? Really appreciate the help by the way!

Comment: while the conclusion is correct, the reasoning might not be. riemann integrable criterion says that it is integrable if the set of discontinuity is a null set. If the set is countable, we know it is a null set. if the set is not countable, we can't conclude that it is not a null set. cantor set is one such example that is uncountable and yet have measure $0$.

Comment: Ah thank you. Appreciate your help